# How do I resolve : value error : time data '1901-Jan' does not match format '%Y-%m

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline
def parser(x):
    return dt.datetime.strptime('19'+x, '%Y-%m')

series = pd.read_csv('datasets/shampoo_sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
print(series.head())
```

error:

> Value error: time data '1901-Jan' does not match format '%Y-%m'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: After test data it seems there is only last digit of year, so for parse `1-12` to `2001-12-01` is necessary use:

```
def parser(x):
    return dt.datetime.strptime('200'+x, '%Y-%m')

series = pd.read_csv('shampoo.csv', 
                      header=0, 
                      parse_dates=[0], 
                      index_col=0, 
                      squeeze=True, 
                      date_parser=parser)
print(series.head())
Month
2001-01-01    266.0
2001-02-01    145.9
2001-03-01    183.1
2001-04-01    119.3
2001-05-01    180.3
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: still giving error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: @Pavan - Edited answer. If still not working, is possible share data if not confidental?

Comment: the dataset is available in kaggle: link: https://www.kaggle.com/guangningyu/sales-of-shampoo

Comment: @ jasrael The dataset had other strings so I got the second error .. otherwise your suggestion worked..thanks

Comment: @Pavan - Now I am confused, solution working for you perfect?